# Run ansible playbook with --check and --diff fails on package which is not there

Tags: ansible

I have an Ansible playbook which downloads a package and puts it in a folder.
Next Ansible will unpack this package.

```yaml
- name: Unpacking package
  unarchive:
    src: xxx
    dest: yyy
    remote_src: yes
```

This works fine when I run the playbook but it fails when I use `--diff` and `--check` options. Of course, it's normal because the package is not "really" downloaded and it isn't in the `src` folder. This means the unpacking will fail.

Now what is a good way to workaround this and make a dry-run using `--check` and `--diff` succeed?

Comment: One way could be to use `ignore_errors: "{{ ansible_check_mode }}"` on your task: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_checkmode.html#skipping-tasks-or-ignoring-errors-in-check-mode

Comment: An other way is to decide that downloading the package is a tasks that does not really change your system and can safely be ran in check mode, in which case you can use `check_mode: false`. The choice really depends on your requirement (i.e. check you can download the file or that you can unarchive it once it is here....)